# How to show multiple images from Firebase Storage?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I'm trying to show all images the user uploaded to Firebase Storage to a single note but it's only giving me one image when using `note.image` or duplicating the images when using `image['url']`. I want to use `note.image`. I've tried a few things but no success.
Sorry for adding a ton of code. I'm not sure what all needs to be changed and not sure how to to explain it all... I'm new.

Here is my model that shows a single image:

```
class NoteModel {

  String? image;
  String? id;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  Timestamp? date;
  String? userId;

  NoteModel({
    this.image,
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.date,
    this.userId
  });

  factory NoteModel.fromJson(DocumentSnapshot streamSnapshot){

    return NoteModel(
      image: streamSnapshot['image'],
      id: streamSnapshot.id,
      title: streamSnapshot['title'],
      description: streamSnapshot['description'],
      date: streamSnapshot['date'], 
      userId: streamSnapshot['userId']
      );  
  }
}
```

```
class FirestoreService{

  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future insertNote(
  String image, 
  String title, 
  String description, 
  String userId)async{
    try{
      await firestore.collection('notes').add({
        "image":image,
        "title":title,
        "description":description,
        "date":DateTime.now(),
        "userId":userId
      });
 } catch(e){
 }
  }
```

Where I'm using note.image and want to see the multiple images the user uploaded:

```
 FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("notes")
              .where('userId', isEqualTo: user?.uid ?? '')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length ?? 0,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final NoteModel note =
                      NoteModel.fromJson(snapshot.data.docs[index]);
                  return Column(children: [
                    Center(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        ),
                        child: Card(
                          color: Color(0xFFf4f5f7),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              right: 10, top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10),
                          elevation: 8.0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Image.network(

                                note.image!, // HERE
                                
                                errorBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                    Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
                                  return const Text(
                                      'error loading image or no image found');
                                },
                              ),
```

My AddNoteScreen where I can upload multiple images to Firebase Storage:

```
 File? imageFile;
  String? fileName;

  Future<void> uploadMultipleImages() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final List<XFile>? pickedImages = await picker.pickMultiImage();
    if (pickedImages == null) {
      return null;
    }
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    }); 
    await Future.forEach(pickedImages, (XFile image) async {
      fileName = image.name;
      imageFile = File(image.path);

      try {
        await firebaseStorage.ref(fileName).putFile(imageFile!);
      } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    });

    setState(() {
      loading = false;
    });

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text("All images uploaded successfully")));
  }
```

Loading images from Firebase Storage:

```
  Future<List> loadImages() async {
    List<Map> files = [];
    final ListResult result = await firebaseStorage.ref().listAll();
    final List<Reference> allFiles = result.items;
    await Future.forEach(allFiles, (Reference file) async {
      final String fileUrl = await file.getDownloadURL();
      files.add({
        "url": fileUrl,
        "path": file.fullPath,
      });
    });
    print(files);
    return files;
  }
```

Using `imageUrl: image['url']` shows all the images:

```
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  uploadMultipleImages();
                },
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 150,
                  child: imageFile == null
                      ? Center(child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_rounded, size: 80))
                      : Center(
                          child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_rounded, size: 80)),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 300,
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: loadImages(),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                      return ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final Map image = snapshot.data[index];
                            return Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Card(
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                        height: 200,
                                        child: Stack(
                                          children: [
                                            CachedNetworkImage(
                                              // imageUrl: note.image!, 
                                              imageUrl: image['url'], 
                                              placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                                  Image.asset(
                                                      'assets/placeholder.jpg'),
                                              errorWidget:
                                                  (context, url, error) =>
                                                      Icon(Icons.error),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
```

```
ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (imageFile == null ||
                             titleController.text.isEmpty ||
                             descriptionController.text.isEmpty 
                           ) {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                content: Text("All fields are required")));

                          } else {
                            setState(() {
                              loading = true;
                            });

                            String imageUrl = await FirebaseStorage.instance
                                .ref(fileName)
                                .putFile(imageFile!)
                                .then((result) {
                              return result.ref.getDownloadURL();
                            });

                            await FirestoreService().insertNote(
                                imageUrl,
                                titleController.text,
                                descriptionController.text,
                                widget.user.uid);

                            CollectionReference notes =
                                firestore.collection('notes');
                            QuerySnapshot allResults = await notes.get();
                            allResults.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot result) {
                              print(result.data());
                            });
```

NotesScreen page where I'm trying to use Swiper. Here it duplicates(loops?) the images using note.image! and image['url']:

```
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("notes")
              .where('userId', isEqualTo: user.uid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot streamSnapshot) {
            if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
              if (streamSnapshot.data.docs.length > 0) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: streamSnapshot.data.docs.length ?? 0,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final NoteModel note =
                          NoteModel.fromJson(streamSnapshot.data.docs[index]);
                      return Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                        margin:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18, left: 15, right: 15),
                        child: Column(children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 210,
                            child: Expanded(
                              child: FutureBuilder(
                                  future: loadImages(),
                                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                      return const Center(
                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                      );
                                    }
                                    return Swiper(
                                        loop: false,
                                        pagination: SwiperPagination(
                                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                          builder: DotSwiperPaginationBuilder(
                                              activeSize: 7,
                                              size: 6,
                                              color: Colors.grey[100],
                                              activeColor: Colors.grey[600]),
                                        ),
                                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length ?? 0,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                          final Map image =
                                              snapshot.data[index];
                                          return Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                              child: Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Card(
                                                    child: SizedBox(
                                                      height: 200,
                                                      child: SizedBox(
                                                        height: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                context)
                                                            .size
                                                            .height,
                                                        width: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                context)
                                                            .size
                                                            .width,
                                                        child: ClipRRect(
                                                          borderRadius:
                                                              const BorderRadius
                                                                      .only(
                                                                  topLeft: Radius
                                                                      .circular(
                                                                          15),
                                                                  topRight: Radius
                                                                      .circular(
                                                                          15)),
                                                          child:
                                                              CachedNetworkImage(
                                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                            imageUrl:
                                                            note.image!,
                                                               // image['url'],
                                                            placeholder: (context,
                                                                    url) =>
                                                                Image.asset(
                                                                    'assets/placeholder.jpg'),
                                                            errorWidget: (context,
                                                                    url,
                                                                    error) =>
                                                                const Icon(Icons
                                                                    .error),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ));
                                        });
                                  }),
                            ),
                          ),
```

[image: screenshot]

There could be many things going wrong here so if you need to see more please let me know..

I have very little experience with this. Any help would be very much appreciated!

[image: Cloud Firestore]

[image: firebase storage]

And apologies, I might be slow to respond.

EDIT on NotesScreen:

```
         child:
                                                              ListView.builder(
                                                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {  
                                                                return CachedNetworkImage(
                                                                  imageUrl: note.image!,
                                                                  // image['url'],
                                                                  placeholder: (context,
                                                                      url) =>
                                                                  Image.asset(
                                                                      'assets/placeholder.jpg'),
                                                                  errorWidget: (context,
                                                                      url,
                                                                      error) =>
                                                                  const Icon(Icons
                                                                      .error),
                                                                      );
                                                                      }),
```

EDIT:

Changed from String to List in my AddNoteScreen(to match my FirestoreService page?) but am now getting a new error

```
   List imageUrl = await FirebaseStorage.instance
                                .ref(fileName)
                                .putFile(imageFile!)
                                .then((result) {
                              return result.ref.getDownloadURL(); // HERE 
                            });

                            await FirestoreService().insertNote(
                                imageUrl,
```

I get `The return type 'Future<String> isn't a 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>', as required by closure's context.`

Here is my FirestoreService page:

```
class FirestoreService{

  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future insertNote(
  List image, 
  String title, 
  String description, 
  String userId)async{
    try{
      await firestore.collection('notes').add({
        "image":image,
        "title":title,
        "description":description,
        "date":DateTime.now(),
        "userId":userId
      });
 } catch(e){
 }
  }
```

Comment: could you show a screenshot of what's appearing on the emulator, and your documents on firestore

Comment: could you include api response? @LeenaMarie

Comment: you want show images like a slider? or show them in column? @LeenaMarie

Comment: Yes I would like to show it in a slider and sorry I don't know what an api response is

Comment: print("data = ${snapshot.data.docs}"); before `return ListView.builder` and show me the result. @LeenaMarie

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to store uploaded images in a list in firestore, with this approach you can able to get list of uploaded images by particular user.

And after that you have to change String to List your model like below code

```
class NoteModel {
  List<String>? image;
  String? id;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  Timestamp? date;
  String? userId;

 NoteModel({
 this.image,
 this.id,
 this.title,
 this.description,
 this.date,
 this.userId
 });
  factory NoteModel.fromJson(DocumentSnapshot streamSnapshot){
     return NoteModel(
      image: List<String>.from(streamSnapshot["image"].map((x) => x)),
      id: streamSnapshot.id,
      title: streamSnapshot['title'],
      description: streamSnapshot['description'],
      date: streamSnapshot['date'], 
      userId: streamSnapshot['userId']
    );  
  }
 }
```

And then wrap CachedNetworkImage() with ListView.builder or GridView.builder to show all the uploaded images.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I changed String to List in my FirestoreService page but I'm getting "The argument 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type List<dynamic>' in my AddNoteScreen where I have ```  await FirestoreService().insertNote(imageUrl,```. I also changed my model to yours but I'm getting "The argument type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' on my NoteScreen where I have ```CachedNetworkImage(fit: BoxFit.cover, imageUrl: note.image!```

Comment: have you wrapped CachedNetworkImage() with ListView.builder or GridView.builder?

Comment: still getting the same errors, did I use ListView.builder properly? Added an edit at the bottom of my question

Comment: @LeenaMarie if you updated the model to List of images then in list view you have to use it like this imageUrl: note.image![index],

Comment: Thank you!! That solved the second error in my first comment. For the first error, please see the new edit to my question at the bottom

Comment: @LeenaMarie just change List imageUrl = ... ; into String imageUrl = .... ;

Answer (score 1):

First change your dadas model to this:

```
class NoteModel {

  List<String?>? images; //<--- change this
  String? id;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  Timestamp? date;
  String? userId;

  NoteModel({
    this.images,
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.date,
    this.userId
  });

  factory NoteModel.fromJson(DocumentSnapshot streamSnapshot){

    return NoteModel(
      images: streamSnapshot['image'],
      id: streamSnapshot.id,
      title: streamSnapshot['title'],
      description: streamSnapshot['description'],
      date: streamSnapshot['date'], 
      userId: streamSnapshot['userId']
      );  
  }
}
```

then change your `Card` to this:

```
Card(
    color: Color(0xFFf4f5f7),
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10),
    elevation: 8.0,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: images
                    .map((e) => SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          child: Image.network(
                            e!, // HERE
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            errorBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
                              return const Text(
                                  'error loading image or no image found');
                            },
                          ),
                        ))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: I'm getting "Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform"

Comment: can you show me the full error message?

Comment: I added an s ``` images: streamSnapshot['image_'],``` removed it and I am now getting "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String?>?'"

Comment: Can you print("data = ${snapshot.data.docs}"); before return ListView.builder and show me the result? @LeenaMarie

Comment: Added another screenshot, is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: Your firebase just send one image.not a list.

Comment: How can I fix that ?

Comment: sorry you need change your  firebase and I don't know the firebase side, I just know about flutter side.